# Excel Formula for looking at different account #'s, and finding descriptions of each, and making sets of them in separate columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image: Image of my worksheets]

I have 12,000+ rows to sort through of this data and help would be so appreciated!

So firstly I need to check for the account names of a unique id.

So let's say for A00001 , there is Products, Swaps, and Adjustments-Change .

As you can see these account names are listed multiple times for the unique ID A00001 , but I only need to the know which account names are included for A0001, not how many times each is listed.

I'll take those 3 accounts names that I found, and put them in a "group" tab in the worksheet, as shown in the bottom picture, and create a group #1. If another unique ID within the 12,000+ rows only contains the account names Products, Swaps and Adjustments-Change accounts, then I'll assign it to Group #1 ( the green circle).

In the next set of unique ID, A00002, the account names that reoccur are Products and Swaps. So I'll create a group #2. I won't assigned this to group #1 because it doesn't contain all 3 of the accounts names that group #1 has.

For A00003, it contains only Products and Swaps, so I will assign it a group #2.

So what I'm asking is, is there an excel formula or VBA code that I could use to automate this?

Comment: Approximately how many groups do you expect to end up with: tens; hundreds or more?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your post has been downvoted is that you haven't produced any code or formulae that would demonstrate you have at least attempted to solve this problem. And your question is rather vague:

> is there VBA code to automate this?

Answer: Yes!

It's not really our job to articulate your question for you, which is why responses to your post are rather sparse. However, there are a couple of points in your question that may also be of use to others so I'll answer as best I can.

Point 1: whenever you have reasonably large datasets (in your case 200,000), it's usually better to read the data into a `Variant` array and process the data within VBA. That's a simple task `v = Range(A1:D200000).Value2` and is remarkably fast.

Point 2: I presume your account names aren't necessarily sorted. So one client could have a 'Products and Swaps' combo whereas another could have 'Swaps and Products'. You haven't stated this, but I guess we have to cater for the possibility. In these cases, a solution is to convert each item to a numerical index which allows something similar to binary addition. If for example, 'Products'=1, 'Swaps'=2 and 'Adj'=4 then a combo of products and swaps (in whatever order) will give a unique sum of 3; swaps and adj uniquely give 6, etc.

The solution to your task probably lies somewhere down this road. The code below will help you get started with it, and I have commented throughout to give you further guidance.

I note this is your first post, so I ought to explain that the purpose of this site is not to provide a pro-bono coding service. It's meant to help you and others when you hit an insurmountable obstacle. Please therefore try to understand the code and familiarise yourself with VBA so that you can develop this skeleton code for yourself; and, if I may take the liberty of offering advice, avoid response comments along the lines of "It won't work."

Good luck with your project, paste the following code into a `Module` in your VBA Editor:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const UNIQUE_ID_INDEX As Integer = 0
Private Const ACC_LIST_INDEX As Integer = 1
Private Const ALLOCATION_INDEX As Integer = 2
Private Const GROUP_NAME_INDEX As Integer = 0
Private Const GROUP_LIST_INDEX As Integer = 1
Private Const ROW_KEY As String = "row"
Private Const GROUP_KEY As String = "group"
Private Const SOURCE_SHEET_FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
Private Const SOURCE_SHEET_FIRST_COL As Long = 1
Private Const SOURCE_SHEET_LAST_COL As Long = 3
Private Const GROUP_SHEET_FIRST_ROW As Long = 1
Private Const GROUP_SHEET_FIRST_COL As Long = 2
Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim grp As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim output() As Variant
    Dim idList As Collection
    Dim groupList As Collection
    Dim accList As Collection
    Dim accKeyList As Collection
    Dim accIndex As Long
    Dim accName As String
    Dim idItems As Variant
    Dim uniqueID As String
    Dim groupItems As Variant
    Dim maxSize As Long
    Dim added As Boolean
    Dim c As Long
    Dim h As Long
    Dim v As Variant

    ' Read the data from the data sheet
    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'adjust to your source data sheet name.
    lastRow = src.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=src.Cells(1), _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False).Row

    data = src.Range(src.Cells(SOURCE_SHEET_FIRST_ROW, SOURCE_SHEET_FIRST_COL), _
           src.Cells(lastRow, SOURCE_SHEET_LAST_COL)).Value2

    'Process the data into lists of unique acc names and IDs
    Set accList = New Collection
    Set accKeyList = New Collection
    Set idList = New Collection
    c = 1
    For h = 1 To UBound(data, 1)

        'Convert account names to unique binary indexes
        accName = data(h, 2)
        accIndex = GetOrAdd(accName, accList, c, added)
        If added Then
            accKeyList.Add accName, CStr(c)
            c = c + c
        End If

        'Create a list of uniqueIDs and a list of row numbers for each new uniqueID
        uniqueID = data(h, 3)
        idItems = GetOrAdd(uniqueID, idList, Array(uniqueID, New Collection, New Collection), added)
        If added Then idItems(ALLOCATION_INDEX).Add h, ROW_KEY

        'Add the account index to this uniqueID group
        Call IgnoreOrAdd(CStr(accIndex), idItems(ACC_LIST_INDEX), accIndex)
    Next

    'Sum each account index in the uniqueID group
    'to obtain a binary value that is unique
    'to this combination of account names
    'and create a new group if the binary value is new.
    Set groupList = New Collection
    maxSize = 0
    c = 1
    For Each idItems In idList
        h = 0
        For Each v In idItems(ACC_LIST_INDEX)
            h = h + v
        Next

        groupItems = GetOrAdd(CStr(h), groupList, Array(c, idItems(ACC_LIST_INDEX)), added)
        If added Then
            c = c + 1
            'Get max size of list to dimension output array
            h = groupItems(GROUP_LIST_INDEX).Count
            If h > maxSize Then maxSize = h
        End If

        'Assign group name to uniqueID
        idItems(ALLOCATION_INDEX).Add groupItems(GROUP_NAME_INDEX), GROUP_KEY

    Next

    'Write the group output onto the source data sheet
    ReDim output(1 To UBound(data, 1), 1 To 1)
    For Each idItems In idList
        output(idItems(ALLOCATION_INDEX).Item(ROW_KEY), 1) = _
            idItems(ALLOCATION_INDEX).Item(GROUP_KEY)
    Next
    src.Cells(SOURCE_SHEET_FIRST_ROW, SOURCE_SHEET_LAST_COL + 1) _
        .Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output

    'Write the group summary output onto the summary sheet
    Set grp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'adjust to your group summary sheet name.
    ReDim output(1 To maxSize + 1, 1 To groupList.Count + 1)
    output(1, 1) = "Group #"
    'Loop through group list to read the individual acc names.
    c = 2
    For Each groupItems In groupList
        output(1, c) = groupItems(GROUP_NAME_INDEX)
        h = 2
        For Each v In groupItems(GROUP_LIST_INDEX)
            accName = accKeyList(CStr(v))
            output(h, c) = accName
            h = h + 1
        Next
        c = c + 1
    Next
    grp.Cells(GROUP_SHEET_FIRST_ROW, GROUP_SHEET_FIRST_COL) _
        .Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output

End Sub
Private Function GetOrAdd(ByVal key As String, _
                          ByRef col As Collection, _
                          ByVal newValue As Variant, _
                          Optional ByRef added As Boolean) As Variant
    Dim v As Variant

    v = Empty
    On Error Resume Next
    v = col(key)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If IsEmpty(v) Then
        v = newValue
        col.Add v, key
        added = True
    Else
        added = False
    End If

    GetOrAdd = v

End Function
Private Sub IgnoreOrAdd(ByVal key As String, _
                        ByRef col As Variant, _
                        ByVal newValue As Variant, _
                        Optional ByRef added As Boolean)
    Dim v As Variant

    v = Empty
    On Error Resume Next
    v = col(key)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If IsEmpty(v) Then
        col.Add newValue, key
        added = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Ambie, this one of the best answers for a newbie I have seen so far on this site. I guess there is nothing left for anyone to add to this post of yours!
Given that I myself started learning VBA not that long time ago, I just wanted to make sure that my understanding is correct about this code that it is a general one in cases of encoding strings to some numbers.

Comment: @Tango_Mike, yes, the concept is generic, but the code itself would need a little adapting to fit someone else's worksheet layout. The crux of it lies in using `Collections` which must have unique `keys` (ie string values) as a means of avoiding duplicates, so any string could be represented as a numerical value. I didn't want to write a complete solution for this OP, so there's nothing in here to deal with the likes of blank cells, incorrect data types, etc. so some decent error handling would need to be added too.

Comment: @ Ambie,Thank you very much for clarification. Just one additional question, if I may. I have read that when identifying `Collection` object, it should be in the Class Module; yet. I have noticed that you recommend putting the code inside a module. Is it a requirement to work with collections in a class module, or is it just for "neat programming" purposes?

Comment: @Tango_Mike, I can't say I've heard of that. I do prefer to code using `Classes` rather than `Modules` but there's no requirement to use `Collections` in a `Class`, and I've written plenty of VBA programmes that do so in a `Module`. I've recommended a `Module` for this OP to keep the answer simple. I'd say it's probably simply a matter of taste.